# Convert JSON URL to GeoJSON in QGIS 3.10 Coruna

Tags: qgis, python, geojson, json, url

I am using Python in QGIS 3.10 to convert a JSON URL into a GeoJSON. Here is the first part of the code :

```
import requests
r = requests.get(' http://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/id/floods ')
data = r.json()
# the result is directly a dictionary and if we examine the keys
data.keys()
[u'@context', u'meta', u'items']
# look at the first item
data['items'][0]
{u'severityLevel': 4, u'isTidal': True, u'description': u'North Sea Coast from Whitby to Filey’, u'timeSeverityChanged': u'2015-02-02T19:32:00', u'eaRegionName': u'North East', u'floodAreaID': u'122WAC953', u'timeMessageChanged': u'2015-02-02T19:32:00', u'floodArea': {u'county': u'North Yorkshire', u'riverOrSea': u'North Sea', u'@id': u'http://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/id/floodAreas/122WAC953', u'polygon': u'http://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/id/floodAreas/122WAC953/polygon', u'notation': u'122WAC953'}, u'timeRaised': u' 2015-02-02T19:32:00', u'message': u'None.', u'@id': u'http://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/id/floods/91436', u'eaAreaName': u'Yorkshire', u'severity': u'Warning no longer in force'}
```

I got this error message in QGIS:
[image]

Any idea how to solve the issue?

Comment: can you do something like somevar = data['items´] and see what happens?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Open the URL in a browser and note that `items[]` is empty...

Comment: Please don't use a picture of text in your question, it is very difficult to read for some users and impossible for screen readers, and google.